# How to extract a filename using regex from an absolute path

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract just the filename from the following line:

```
"GET /mapitzend/public/components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 200 26651
```

In this case the expected result should be "font-awesome.css"
I have gotten this far with my regex:

```
\"(.[^\"]+)\s+HTTP
```

eith the regex above it returns: "GET /mapitzend/public/components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP

What am I missing here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

`(?<=\/)[^\s\/]*(?=\s*HTTP)`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4gs5x2/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\/)` - positive lookbehind to find the position immediately preceded by a `/`
- `[^\s\/]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character which is neither a whitespace character nor a `/`
- `(?=\s*HTTP)` - Positive lookahead to match until the position which is immediately followed by 0+ whitespaces followed by `HTTP`.

Answer (score 0):

While extracting the file name using `regex` is possible, it's easier for start to extract the path using `regex` and then get the filename using [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) or [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$line = '"GET /mapitzend/public/components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 200 26651';

$m = array();
if (preg_match('/GET (.*) HTTP/', $line, $m)) {
    $filename = basename($m[1]);
}
```

Using only `regex`:

```
if (preg_match('#GET /(.*/)*(.*) HTTP#', $line, $m)) {
    $filename = $m[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using properties of a filename which has certain extension like `.css`,`.html` you can use following regex.

**Regex:** `[^\/]+?\.[a-z]+`

**Explanation:**

`[^\/]+?` matches a string whose preceding character was `/`.

`\.[a-z]+` matches the extension making sure it's a file.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RaSRJH/4/)**